# Plotting ratings matrix

Tags: matlab, python, matrix, sparse-matrix, matplotlib

Hello fellows and folks.

I have been looking to do this for 1 month and still cannot find the way to do it.

Here’s what’s going on:

I have a csv file called ratings.csv with the following structure:

```
userID, movieID, rating
3,  12, 5
2, 7,  4
```

The rating scale goes from 0 to 5 stars. I want to be able to plot the sparsity of the matrix like it’s done in the following picture:

[image: pictiure]

As you can see, ratings scale goes from 0 to 5 on the right. It is a very well thought plot.

I have Matlab, Python, R etc. Could you come up with something and help me? I’ve tried hard but I cannot find the way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand you question. Do you want to repeat the plot?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thats the idea but I cannot find the way to do it.

Comment: Anyway, your picture looks like it is simply the output of Matlab's `imagesc(A)`, once you have converted the ratings to a sparse matrix `A` (which, I assume, you know how to do with `spconvert` or the three-argument version of `sparse`).

Comment: Is your answer supposed to be an update to your post?

Comment: No, it is the answer. I have updated the whole thing!

Comment: You just added code without any explanation, consider adding an explanation. Also, mentioning why @FedericoPoloni solution does not work.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Your approach also works, Federico. I sticked to mine but I think your approach is even better than mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it this way though it may had been easier to plot it the way Federico has mentioned before: imagesc(A).

I declared an **A** matrix of zeros of mxn dimension and then loaded the ratings. I then applied HeatMap(A) which yields the image below.

```matlab
A = importdata('u.data');
user_id = A(:, 1);
movie_id = A(:, 2);
rating = A(:, 3);

% Build matrix R 
R = zeros(943, 1682);

for i=1:100000
R(user_id(i), movie_id(i)) = rating(i);

end


m = HeatMap(R,’Xlabel’,’I did it!’)
ax = hm.plot; % 'ax' will be a handle to a standard MATLAB axes.
colorbar('Peer', ax); % Turn the colorbar on
caxis(ax, [0 5]); % Adjust the color limits
```

[image]